# Java Tile Game Zooming

Tags: java, 2d, zooming, tile, graphic

I am building a 2D top-down tile based game in Java. Naturally you can pan around and zoom in on the game, currently zooming in on 10 different levels, where each tile ranges 10x10 pixels to 100x100 pixels appropriately. Currently, the the tiles for each zoom level are stored in separate sprite sheets, read in at the startup of the program and stored in a buffered image array. I am sure this can't be the best way to go about this.

I am looking for any tips to enhance efficiency for the long-term, would it be better to have the 100x100 tiles only and scale them dynamically in java; somehow use vector graphics in java (I'm sure how, but I'm sure google could help me) or what?

Many thanks!

Comment: `svg`s (vector graphics) would be good here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go dynamic.
Normally in computer graphics you use matrices that, applied to the graphics context, modify everything you draw on it.

This is used to modify position, scale, rotation, etc. Rather than subtract the camera position to every tile, you apply the translation once to the graphics context, and then you draw your tiles in world position. The graphics context will take care of placing the tiles in the correct screen space.

I suggest you the following reads:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html

Comment: When using affine transform for the main graphics component, does the computer render out, or at least calculate what is outside the visible area. Obviously if the game has to calculate all the usual stuff, but for the entire map, not just the visible area, it would take a lot more CPU usage. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMessias if a tile is outside the view, it won't be rendered, but it will stil waste resources. For culling you still need to do optimizations in your code. Generally you have a rectangle containing the camera frustrum, which you need to modify with translations and zooming applied. Then you apply culling based on that and send to render only what's visible. You don't want to do matrix computation on invisible objects!

Comment: This answer might have just changed my life.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing fixed zooming (i.e. each zoom level is a fixed distance from the camer), as opposed to fluid zooming (the player can zoom in by 3.3x, 7.5x, and not just 1x, 2x, 3x, etc.) then it's massively wasteful to try to solve this by simply applying a zoom transform. It's tempting because that's the least complicated approach, and it's easy to understand from an implementation standpoint, but that means that at maximum zoom-out, you're going to be rendering an area that's 10x larger in the X direction, and 10x larger in the Y direction - so  the **area** of the world that you have to render is 100x larger than at maximum zoom-in. I also doubt that you'll like the way your textures get squished by the hardware as you're zooming out. Computer graphics isn't the same as optics - subpixel rendering, and other things that happen in computer graphics aren't going to make your textures look very good if you hand that task off the the software/hardware.

Even if you do fluid zooming, I would still do level-of-detail textures, and dynamically swap them out depending on the distance between the world being rendered, and the camera.

Also, 10 zoom levels? Are you sure you really need 10 zoom levels? Zoom is usually used in 2D games to allow you to perform different activities at different levels of detail because a particular zoom level is especially well suited for a certain set of activities. I don't remember any 2D game that needed 10 zoom levels to accomplish this. 3-5 is the most I've ever seen, and I've never felt that it wasn't enough. It also seems like a lot of art work to produce the images at every zoom level for 10 zoom levels.

You're also likely going to find that applying an AffineTransform sounds like a good idea, but that it's extremely computationally expensive, and if you need 60fps performance, you're highly unlikely to achieve it this way. Don't take my word for it though, go try it and see how badly it falls over on itself.

Comment: I see your point. I agree with your point on 10 zoom levels being too many. It's only a spare time bit of fun project, so performance isn't vital, but I completely agree you wouldn't need more than 5. I'm relatively new the Java so using an image transform on a simplistic game is probably easier for me, but I completely see your  point, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Its not either one or the other. You can combine fluid zooming (with transformations) and different levels of detail. Take for example Medieval Total War II. When you zoom out, 3D models loose texture quality. And if you zoom out even more, THEY BECOME 2D SPRITES !!

Comment: Also, the maximum zoom-in may not be the "normal zoom". So displaying a 10X bigger screen area may not be that huge, but normal. It all comes down to how many objects you draw and the texture quality (/pixel density) they have.

Comment: A lot of the implementation details will be game-specific, I'm sure. And I agree, it's not a one or the other thing - it a combination of dynamic and level-of-detail in the case of fluid zomming.